# Error in mongodb find method while trying to fetch user's location using router.put method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to find user's location using `router.put` method, by finding the user's mobile number. But the method `User.find` is not working and showing the error **null property cant be set**. Although the method `findbyid` is working.

Follwoing is my code. Please suggest what am I doing wrong.

```
router.put('/updatelocation/:mobileNo',  (req, res) => {
        User.find({mobileNo:req.params.mobileNo}, (err, user) => {
          if (err) {
            res.send(err);
          }
          res.json(user);
          user.name = req.body.name;

          user.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
              res.send(err);
            }
           res.json({ message: 'Food Truck info updated' });
            //res.send(user);
          });

        });
     });
```

Comment: ``User.find({...})`` will return array. Are you getting blank array of user?

Comment: yes i am getting blank array

Comment: Uhm, is it just me or does the „mobileNo” key need to be quoted?

Answer (score 0):

`User.find` will return an array, if you want a single object use `User.findOne`
example:

```
User.findOne({ mobileNo : req.params.mobileNo}, (err, user) => {
   ...
});
```

And if you are using mongoose want to update user [`.update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) or [`.findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate)